# Color combo box and custom color picker

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to c# & wpf so I'm wondering how I should approach this kind of control.

I need to have a combobox that previews basic colors and a custom color picker option. The first 8 items are colors derived from rgb (the values are either 255 or 0) then the last item should show color picker dialog on click.

[color combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu538.png)

[color picker dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQoL6.png)

I need it to look exactly like those images so I can't use the wpf toolkit. Some demos on the internet are either too complex or doesn't match what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for the color ComboBox

You can add a **ComboBoxItem** in the **items collection** and set the **background color** to the color that you wish for and leave the **content** section empty so it won't show any text

**Example :**

[image: Example]